# Top 10 searched ids in a table

Tags: postgresql

I wish to find out the 10 top most searched movies in a `movie` table .

`movie(movie_id , movie_title,rating)` .

I referred to following link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/view-pg-stats.html which states that most_common_vals in pg_stats table. 
But I think it refers to the number of values in a column . Correct me if I am wrong.

Is there a way to find out 10 top most searched movies in the movie table ?

Comment: If with "top searched" you mean those movies where your application sent SQL queries for, then no, this is not logged anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to that those 10 top movies for which search query is fired maximum times . So it should be handled at the application side ?

Comment: Yes, that's the only place where you can do that.